# Exception while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I got the following error.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-09-20 23:08:46.626918+0400 UnitConverter[6852:10110844] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Code and Image attached.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let webVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webVC") as! ViewController
        webVC.lblCategory.text = self.uc.categories[indexPath.row]
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Something is nil that shouldn't be. In this case, `lblCategory` because, as Sulthan says below, the view hasn't been loaded so the connection hasn't been set up.

Comment: @Kevin Nah, he's accessing an outlet before the view has been loaded (since he is not accessing the `view` or calling `loadViewIfNeeded`).

Comment: @Sulthan Ah yes, that would do it.

Comment: I bind the display of webVC from interface builder. I dragged the table cell to the view and bind show to it. so what is the workaround to fix this issue. @Sulthan

Comment: @JamalAbdulNasir Call `webVC.loadViewIfNeeded()` before accessing `lblCategory`.

Comment: Make sure you have connected `lblCategory` label in the `webVC` storyboard.

Comment: @Sulthan If the author removes that line and the `lblCategory` isn't correctly set, that should crash at some point, if he tries on use it on its code in `viewDidLoad()` doing `self.lblCategory = "Test"`. It could help then understand where lies the issue exactly.

Comment: @Larme i tested that already. and it is working.

Comment: And...? Does it crashes? If on the line `self.lblCategory = "Test"`? If yes, that's the issue. If not, is `self.uc.categories[indexPath.row]` nil? Also, did you try by setting a String property `categoryText`, do instead `webVC.categoryText = self.uc.categories[indexPath.row]`, and on viewDidAppear() (or else), do `self.lblCategory.text = categoryText`?

Answer (score 0):

Outlets are connected when the view is loaded. The view is loaded when the view is first accessed.

Before you don't load the view `webVC.lblCategory` will be `nil`, crashing your app. To fix it either access the `view` first:

```
_ = webVC.view
webVC.lblCategory.text = ...
```

or load the view explicitly

```
webVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
webVC.lblCategory.text = ...
```

Comment: Another way is to use String property to hold that value and set it to the label when the load is done. That's a common technique used on `prepareForSegue()` that may be worth mentionning.

Comment: still the same error. and also the lbl is connected to the webVC.

Comment: @Larme i am not using `prepareForSegue()`.

Comment: @JamalAbdulNasir I said it's the same technique. Because the reason is the same: The IBOutlet are not loaded.

Comment: What about `self.uc.categories`? Could that be `nil`?

Comment: @Sulthan it is not. it prints the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string property in your view controller and set the string property from table view didselect. Then in you view controller, you can set value to your label outlet.